# How to get values from website which is always changing and connected to database?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am using `python`, `selenium` and other packages as per my need. I am creating GUI(Graphical User Interface) where it will show total number of people passes threw the gate.
we already have hardware which directly report to particular website which is written in `php` and database are `sql` and `mariadb.`

```
<span class="info-box-number f28 fc-666" id="tot_count">11</span>
```

This is the sample of code where, I want to capture '11' from this. I tried with 'id', 'class' and 'xpath' to capture this with `.text` but so far I can't find the solution. I refer some other questions but it didn't help me.

- So, Idea is to create GUI interface which updates every second and show the number of people passes. I do have to get some other values with it which also, in similar format, same database with different class, id and xpath.

*Note:* All the class and ids are unique which I want to capture.

I am open to suggestion if someone has better idea,
your suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: pleass add what you have tried and what was the error

Comment: as PDHide said include a simple code of what you have done so far !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the *text* `11` you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `class_name` and `get_attribute("textContent")`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_class_name("info-box-number").get_attribute("textContent"))
  ```
- Using `css_selector` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.info-box-number#tot_count").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `xpath` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(., 'info-box-number') and @id='tot_count']").text)
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CLASS_NAME` and `get_attribute("textContent")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "info-box-number"))).get_attribute("textContent"))
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.info-box-number#tot_count"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., 'info-box-number') and @id='tot_count']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried exactly the same in first place just forgot to put appropriate wait time.